# error MSB8008: Specified platform toolset (v120) is not installed or invalid

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I've downloaded a c++ project. I opened the `.sln` file and I tried to build the project. I got the following error:

`error MSB8008: Specified platform toolset (v120) is not installed or invalid. Please make sure that a supported PlatformToolset value is selected.`

I ve already checked that the platform toolset is set to `v120`. What is the problem here?

Comment: Do you have Visual Studio 2013 installed?  That toolset implies VS2013.

Comment: I ve got vs 2010 vs. What should I do?

Comment: Sounds like you need a more recent version of VS.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Either change the platform toolset of your project to `v100` (as you have installed VS2010) or install VS2013 in order to use `v120`.