# Can I have appearance of MS VC++ 2010 in newer versions of visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, ide, visual-c++-2010

I need to use c++11 features, but MS VC++ 2010 is supporting only part of them.

I can't use newer version of MS visual studio, because of it appearance.
MENU TEXT WITH CAPSLOCK, full of unnecessary options and windows which not all can be hidden.

Is there non-hack way to have appearance of VC++ 2010 in newer versions?

Comment: Which version of VS are you attempting to upgrade to when you get all caps? 2012?

Comment: To 2015. I realised now that in 2015 there are no caps like in 2012, but still it has similar appearance to 2012

Comment: Man, if that's the only problem you have with visual studios newer than 2010, then count yourself lucky.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you could change VS 2013 to look like exactly similar to VS 2010, but! once you have ported your VS 2010 solutions to VS 2012 (platform toolset 110) or VS 2013 (platform toolset 120), you can open the ported solution in VS 2010.

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
  <ConfigurationType>Application</ConfigurationType>
  <UseDebugLibraries>true</UseDebugLibraries>
  <CharacterSet>Unicode</CharacterSet>
  <PlatformToolset>v120</PlatformToolset>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Please see the element *PlatformToolset* under *PropertyGroup* element, VS 2013 would add this information to use vc-runtime 120. You have to have VS 2013 installed to use v120 platform toolset. Have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26100989/error-msb8008-specified-platform-toolset-v120-is-not-installed-or-invalid) to use v120 platform toolset with Visual Studio 2010.

On the flip side Visual Studio 2013 has this provision to select v100 toolset, you can open VS 2010 project in VS 2013 and specify the platform toolset (please see the screenshot)

[image]